# MS SQL, invalid object name

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Okay, let me make it short, I can delete a whole row from database using this code:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM [master].[dbo].[TestTBL] WHERE Agent_ID = '{$_SESSION["agentid"]}' ";
```

but when I try:

```
$sql = "DELETE username FROM [master].[dbo].[TestTBL] WHERE Agent_ID = '{$_SESSION["agentid"]}' ";
```

I also tried to make it [name], but I still get Invalid Object Name username...

I want to delete only the username of a certain Agent_ID 
Any help will be much appreciated. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE username FROM [tableName]
       ^
```

You cant delete one column using DELETE command. You have to delete a whole row

```
DELETE FROM [tableName]
```

> want to delete only the username of a certain Agent_ID

You can use UPDATE command to change some information

```
UPDATE [tableName] SET username=NULL WHERE Agent_ID=1  // or whatever value
```

Comment: but can I use update, I'll just set the username to blank by passing a newly  declared $blank = " ";

Comment: Yes you can, i just mentioned it

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'll try it, I'll comment back if that would work :D. Thanks for the comment sir.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, I think this is the second time you helped me. I owe you two now :)) Thanks Sir.

Comment: That's so kind of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` query to empty that column.

```
$sql = "UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TestTBL] 
SET username = NULL WHERE Agent_ID = '{$_SESSION["agentid"]}' ";
```